# prove that an isosceles triangle has the largest area

Tags: analysis, optimization, triangles

Inside this angle, alpha is place in a segment of length whose ends are on the sides of the angle so that the area of ABC was maximum

Comment: Compared to which shapes?

Comment: the task sounds like this :
Inside this angle, alpha place a segment of length a, the ends of which are on the sides of the angle, so that the area of ABC was the maximum

Comment: Yes, it is possible; but there are simpler ways. E.g., draw the edge $a$ and find the locus of all points $A$ from which $a$ is seen under the given angle $\alpha$.

Comment: sorry the meaning of my work in the application of the method of Lagrange multipliers

Comment: @StanislavProkhorov You should edit your clarifications into the question, not just put them in comments.

Comment: @J.G. sorry, I'm new at this.

Answer (score 0):

Let the sides meeting at an angle $A$ have lengths $x,\,y$. You want to prove that, subject to $x^2+y^2-2xy\cos A=a^2$, the maximum of $\frac{1}{2}xy\sin A$ (or equivalently $xy$) takes $x=y$. So use the Lagrangian $L=xy+\lambda (x^2+y^2-2xy\cos A-a^2)$. Then $0=\partial_x L=y+\lambda (2x-2y\cos A)$, i.e. $2\lambda x+(1-2\lambda\cos A)y=0$. Similarly, $2\lambda y+(1-2\lambda\cos A)x=0$. Subtracting, $(x-y)(2\lambda (1+\cos A)-1)=0$. If $x\ne y$, $1-2\lambda\cos A=2\lambda$ so $2\lambda (x+y)=0$, whence $y=-x$. But we require $x,\,y>0$ to maximise area.

Comment: excuse me, what would Sylvester's criteria look like?

Comment: @StanislavProkhorov Sorry, I'm not familiar with "Sylvester's criteria" as a concept in Lagrangian multipliers (all I found was [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion), which doesn't look relevant).

Comment: Your answer is amazing to me, but my professor will require proof, with the first and second differential and the Sylvester Criterion matrix constructed from them.
In my decision I came to a standstill, I do not know what sign has the expression sin^4(90-α/2) - cos^4(90-α/2).

Comment: @StanislavProkhorov I'll leave an analysis of second derivatives to you. BTW, your trigonometric function is $\cos^4\frac{\alpha}{2}-\sin^4\frac{\alpha}{2}=\cos^2\frac{\alpha}{2}-\sin^2\frac{\alpha}{2}=\cos\alpha$.

Comment: WOW is great, but the problem remains if 0<α<pi, the cos at this interval can take both + and -